Is my proof right? (Application of Lagrange mean value theorem)
Question: Set $f\in C^2(a,b)$, $\forall x\in(a,b),f'(x)\neq0$. Prove there exist $\xi,\eta~$ s.t. $\displaystyle\frac{f'(\xi)}{f'(\eta)}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^b-\mathrm{e}^a}{b-a}\mathrm{e}^{-\eta}$.
The usual proof: by Lagrange and Cauchy mean value theorem we have
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},\frac{f'(\eta)}{\mathrm{e}^{\eta}}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{\mathrm{e}^b-\mathrm{e}^a}$$
Which obviously is what we want.
My proof: by Lagrange mean value theorem we have
$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{e}^b-\mathrm{e}^a}{b-a}=\mathrm{e}^{x_0}$. Now set $\eta=\xi=x_0$, then
$$\frac{f'(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x_0}}{\mathrm{e}^{x_0}}=1$$
This is just too silly...I'm wondering if my proof really make sense?

This should work.
